# How can I get a logarithmic custom color scale with pcolormesh?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am trying to draw a heatmap with pcolormesh and I have data with values. This data is from 0-500 but I want the color scale to be logarithmic in nature. Basically it should look like this:
[image]

The heatmap data is in (x,y,data) as used in pcolormesh.
This is the cmap I've written out for this exact scale:

```
cdict1 = {
    'red': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
            (0.16, 237, 237),
            (0.24, 205, 205),
            (0.32, 153, 153),
            (0.40, 83, 83),
            (0.48, 50, 50),
            (0.56, 50, 50),
            (0.64, 5, 5),
            (0.72, 5, 5),
            (0.80, 10, 10),
            (0.88, 44, 44),
            (1, 44, 44)),

    'green': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
            (0.16, 237, 237),
            (0.24, 255, 255),
            (0.32, 240, 240),
            (0.40, 189, 189),
            (0.48, 166, 166),
            (0.56, 150, 150),
            (0.64, 112, 112),
            (0.72, 80, 80),
            (0.80, 31, 31),
            (0.88, 1, 1),
            (1, 1, 1)),

    'blue': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
            (0.16, 237, 237),
            (0.24, 205, 205),
            (0.32, 178, 178),
            (0.40, 159, 159),
            (0.48, 150, 150),
            (0.56, 180, 180),
            (0.64, 176, 176),
            (0.72, 140, 140),
            (0.80, 150, 150),
            (0.88, 70, 70),
            (1, 70, 70)),
}
cm_rgb = LinearSegmentedColormap('bgr', cdict1)
cs = m.pcolormesh(x, y, data, vmin=0, vmax=50e-8,shading='flat', cmap=cm_rgb)
tick_levels = [0, 2e-8, 3e-8, 4e-8, 5e-8, 6e-8, 8e-8, 10e-8, 15e-8, 20e-8, 30e-8, 50e-8]
bar = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation='vertical', shrink=0.5)
bar.set_ticks(tick_levels)
plt.show()
```

When I run this, no color displays. No error.

So basically, my question is, how can I put this all together so that my heatmap uses the custom scale and ticks I've set for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not quite understand how the dictionary is meant to produce the shown colors. In any case it seems that using just a list of those colors is much easier.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap


x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(11), np.arange(11))
data = np.linspace(0,50e-8,100).reshape(10,10)


colors = [(255,255,255),(237,250,194),(205,255,205),
          (153,240,178),(83,189,159),(50,166,150),
          (50,150,180),(5,112,176),(5,80,140),
          (10,31,150),(44,1,70)]

cm_rgb = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', np.array(colors)/255.)
cs = plt.pcolormesh(x, y, data, vmin=0, vmax=50e-8, shading='flat', cmap=cm_rgb)
tick_levels = [0, 2e-8, 3e-8, 4e-8, 5e-8, 6e-8, 8e-8, 10e-8, 15e-8, 20e-8, 30e-8, 50e-8]
bar = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation='vertical', shrink=0.5)
bar.set_ticks(tick_levels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is it! Thanks! I also think I probably messed up on writing the dictionary. It's quite confusing.